# Write algorithm with given time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am preparing for my algorithms and data structures exam and I came across an exercise I can't solve.

The exercise states that I must write an algorithm with time complexity **O(m * n * log(n^3))**. Can anyone explain me how this algorithm would look like and how to approach tasks like this one?

Comment: Hint:  Use nested `for` loops to achieve a given complexity.

Comment: I figured that out, but how do I deal with log(n^3)?

Comment: Thinking outside of the box, let the caller send "m" and "n" as inputs to your algorithm, and then print the number 0 exactly m * n * log(n^3) times. (assuming you can calculate that formula in less than the required complexity, the algorithm will certainly have that time complexity).

Comment: An empty algorithm runs in `O(1)` and therefor meets the requirements. Anything in `O(n)`, like a single loop also meets the requirements. Is it a trick question, or does it say somewhere that `O(m*n*lg(n^3))` has to be a tight bound (or use big-Theta instead of big-Oh)?

Comment: Hint: use a logarithm rule to simplify the expression, and recognize that the result corresponds to (at least one) *extremely important and common* family of algorithms.

Comment: @Paulpro Big-O is commonly (if incorrectly) used to mean Big-Theta.

Comment: `log(n ** 3) == 3 * log(n)`

Comment: Calculate m * n * log(n), and then count to it.  Kind of a silly exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 1 to m
    for j = 1 to n
        k = 1
        while k < n ^ 3
            k = k * 2
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: As I understood, you are having trouble in understanding how to have a loop with running time `O(log n)`. Please read the definition of the logarithm function. Then it will be clear.